# I want to display HTML page in view using flex 4.5 in mobile application so how can i use?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have created 3 view in one of them i want to display static HTML page. How can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a View from my app using StageWebView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        viewActivate="openSWV(event)"
        viewDeactivate="closeSWV(event)"
        title="Help">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="BACK"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/low-res/back.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/mid-res/back.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/high-res/back.png')"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button icon="{BACK}" label.landscape="Back" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="_help">
            <![CDATA[
<html>
<body>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ul>


<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th><th>Blah</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>6</th><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>7</th><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<th>8</th><td>6</td><td>1*</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Blah</th><td>10</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>9</th><td>8</td><td>1*</td><td>1</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>10</th><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</i></p>

</body>
</html>
            ]]>
        </fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;

            private var _swv:StageWebView;

            private function openSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                _swv = new StageWebView();
                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);

                _swv.stage = stage;
                resizeSWV();

                _swv.loadString(_help);
            }

            private function closeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);
                if (! _swv)
                    return;
                _swv.dispose();
                _swv = null;
            }           

            private function resizeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                if (! _swv)
                    return;

                var scale:Number = scale = runtimeDPI / applicationDPI;
                // align to the right-bottom corner
                _swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth - scale * width, stage.stageHeight - scale * height, scale * width, scale * height);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

An implementation of this can be found at
 
http://soenkerohde.com/2010/11/air-mobile-stagewebview-uicomponent/

Cheers